# Regular expression operation cutting off first letter

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

I'm trying to write a Python script that will find all the .py files in a directory tree, and make the following replacement:

myAppl.Variable(VDC).Read() --> MAPort.Read(Model.VDC).Value

However it is currently resulting as the following:

myAppl.Variable(VDC).Read() --> MAPort.Read(Model.DC).Value

Why is the first letter of my variable deleted, what have I done wrong?

```
mypath = "P:\\myTest"
fnames = []
for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(mypath):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".py"):
            fnames.append(root + '\\' + file)
for fname in fnames:
    with open(fname) as reader:
        data = reader.read()
    data = re.sub(r'(myAppl.Variable\(.(.+)\).Read\(\))',
                  r'MAPort.Read(Model.\2).Value', data)
    with open(fname, 'w') as writer:
        writer.write(data)
```

Comment: Because of the dot - `\(.`. Remove it.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fitst char after `(` is matched with a dot due to this part: `\(.` Remove the dot.  You also need to escape the dots that are supposed to match a literal period symbol.

Use

```
r'myAppl\.Variable\(([^()]*)\)\.Read\(\)'
```

and replace with `r'MAPort.Read(Model.\1).Value'`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/V0VXh9/1) and a [Python demo](http://ideone.com/TE6jhJ):

```
import re
rx = r"myAppl\.Variable\(([^()]*)\)\.Read\(\)"
s = "myAppl.Variable(VDC).Read()"
result = re.sub(rx, r"MAPort.Read(Model.\1).Value", s)
print(result)
# => MAPort.Read(Model.VDC).Value
```